# Trying to write IP address to textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ip-address

I am trying to write a simple program that finds the public IP for the computer it is being used on. However, I am not sure how to set the text of the `TextBox` to the IP address that is found. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Function GetMyIP() As IPAddress
        Using wc As New WebClient
            Return IPAddress.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.DownloadData("http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php")))

        End Using
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = (GetMyIP())
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). That would point out to you that you need to use

```
TextBox1.Text = GetMyIP().ToString()
```

Next, if you examine the headers from that web page you will see it returns the result in UTF-8 encoding, so you should use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`. Unfortunately, that still does not work - I will write more on that later.

*However*, WebClient has a [DownloadString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring) which works well in this case:

```
Private Function GetMyIP() As IPAddress
    Using wc As New WebClient
        Dim url = "http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"
        Dim x = wc.DownloadString(url)
        Return IPAddress.Parse(x.Trim())
    End Using

End Function
```

If you still want to use `DownloadData`, you should examine the returned bytes: you would find that the data you want is preceded by the bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF. I do not know why. This is messing up the string that you want if you download it as an array of bytes.

You could use LINQ to remove the strange bytes:

```
Private Function GetMyIP() As IPAddress
    Using wc As New WebClient
        Dim url = "http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"
        Dim x = wc.DownloadData(url)
        Dim y = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Where(Function(b) b < 128).ToArray())
        Return IPAddress.Parse(y)
    End Using

End Function
```

(I could have used `Encoding.ASCII` in there because the bytes over 127 have been removed.)

Note to anyone using this code: from June 2023 use `https://ip.feron.it/` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, I found a slightly easier way of coding this but this is a brilliant response either way. Thank you very much for your time :).

Comment: the URL of this tool is going to change to https://ip.feron.it

Comment: @Luc Thanks: I've added a note in my answer.